# I have downloaded pytorch but not able to run the required cells in VS code. The prompt takes too long to execute the import command

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytorch

[not table to use the torch and highlighted import statements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woS2Y.png)

I tried downloading all the pip statement for pytorch,
upgraded the pip and tried again,
tried connecting to anaconda, but jupyter kernel still takes too long to execute but no output.

Comment: Enough information to answer a question and test proposed answers needs to be included **as text, within the body of the question itself**. Screenshots do not count towards [mre] requirements for the reasons given in [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122)

Comment: Beyond that -- in general, this class of problem is what tracing tools are good for; it's a good place to stop using Jupyter (at least for a while) and use `python -m trace`, or run your program under `pdb`, break partway through the delay, and look at where in the code you're sitting.

Comment: May I know what's going on with the problem? If it has been solved, can you change the status of the answer to help more people with similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the kernel version displayed in the upper right corner to switch and select the correct kernel (python environment with all modules installed).

[image]